# Angular 2: trying to get a project in the detail page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to get one project, from a json file containing projects, but my code doesn't work.

I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. That is because the project variable isn't filled in correctly.

This is the code from the service. How i get the service from the json file:

```
getProject(id: number): Promise<Project> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(x => {
        var project: Project
        x.json().data.forEach(element => {
            if (element.id == id)
            {
                project = element;
            }
        });
        return project;
    }).catch(this.handleError)
}

compareProject(projectA, projectB): number {
    if (projectA.id > projectB.id)
        return -1;
    else if (projectA.id < projectB.id)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

If I debug this code, I actually get the right project.
But it doesn't work in the html file.

This is the page:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteSegment} from '@angular/router'

import { ProjectsService } from '../services/projects.service';
import { Project } from '../models/project';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/pages/projectdetail.page.html',
  providers: [ProjectsService]
})
export class ProjectDetail implements OnInit {
    id: any;
    project: Project;

    constructor(private projectsService: ProjectsService, routeSegment: RouteSegment) {
      this.id = routeSegment.getParam('id');
    }

    getProject() {
        this.projectsService.getProject(this.id).then(project => {
            this.project = project
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProject();
    }    
}
```

And the html, this is where the error is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header headercontainer">
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h1>Project: {{project.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `*ngIf` or you can use `safe-navigation-operator`: `entity?.property`

In your specific case:

```
project?.name
```

[Link to docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, because I am return the project in a promise, the project variable is undefined until it is changed and that is why the page crashes.

I added the following code to check if it is undefined before calling project.name:

```
*ngIf="project"
```

Comment: another solution is to use the `safe-navigation-operator`, see my answer below